# SetTimeout Function: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This code should write a file, run it in a spawn process, and then kill the spawn process if the timeout is reached. However, anytime it triggers the timeout, I get an [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] error.

```
$.get('/path', function(req, res){

// data = contents of a file

fs.writeFile(filename, data,  (err) => {

const child_process = spawn(//run file, {detached: true});

  const wait = setTimeout(function() {
    try {
      process.kill(-runner.pid);
      return res.send("Timeout Message");
    }
  }, 3000);

  runner.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
    clearTimeout(wait);
    fs.unlink(filename, (err) => {
      if (code === 0) return res.send("Good");
      else return res.send('Fail');
    });
  });

  runner.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
  });

  runner.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
  });

  runner.on('error', (err) => {
    clearTimeout(wait);
    fs.unlink(filename, (error) => {
      return res.send("Error");
    });
  });
});
```

}

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: You can only res.send() once in a call. You have it in `exit` and `setTimeout`

Comment: Killing the process may still trigger some of the events you are listening to which would cause you to try to send multiple responses to the request which is what triggers that error.  If you want to avoid the double response, you'd have to set a flag when your timer fires and check that flag in your other event handlers so you can ignore them in that situation.  It's important to realize the `process.kill()` sends a signal to the process tell it to kill itself and that process can decide what to do based on the signal.  It doesn't directly kill it so some events may still occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ending the request twice. Which is the reason why you get `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT`.

The issue with your code is when the timeout is reached, the `.on('exit')` is being called and you're responding again, `clearTimeout` at that point doesn't do anything since that timeout already occurred.

The solution is to either add `res.headersSent` check before each `res.send`

```
runner.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
    clearTimeout(wait);
    fs.unlink(filename, (err) => {
      if (code === 0) return !res.headersSent && res.send("Good");
      else return !res.headersSent && res.send('Fail');
    });
  });
```

Or check whether a timeout has ocurred and respond in `exit` event instead on `timeout` callback. Or just kill the process with a specific signal, and test that signal on `kill` event.

```
 const wait = setTimeout(function() {
      runner.kill('SIGKILL'); // Use whatever signal you prefer
  }, 3000);

 runner.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
    clearTimeout(wait);
    if(signal === 'SIGKILL')
         return res.send("Timeout Message");
    else if (code === 0) 
         return res.send("Good");
    else return res.send('Fail');
    fs.unlink(filename, (err) => {});
  });
```